# Google Pixel device reboots twice after issuing a reboot command

Tags: android-management-api

When I issue a `REBOOT` command to a Google Pixel, it reboots twice in a row. It happens by using the Java SDK, but I was able to reproduce it by using the [Android Management API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/androidmanagement/v1/androidmanagement.enterprises.devices.issueCommand) as well:

```
POST https://androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/LCxxxxxxxx/devices/3ded38daabec2df8:issueCommand?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
   "type": "REBOOT"
}

200
{
  "name": 
  "enterprises/LCxxxxxxxx/devices/3ded38daabec2df8/operations/1569329132626",
  "metadata": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.android.devicemanagement.v1.Command",
  "type": "REBOOT",
  "createTime": "2019-09-24T12:45:32.626Z",
  "duration": "600s",
  "userName": "enterprises/LCxxxxxxxx/users/113818350155522235965"
}
```

This also happens with an Asus Zenfone.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Facing the same issue on Zebra, Honeywell, Samsung and many more devices

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the report, we're looking into the root cause.

As the mitigation for now, please set a shorter timeout like 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Nikita, we've implemented this as a workaround and it works properly!